# Can I remove an inherited nested class from a python class?

Tags: python, inheritance, class-variables

E.g. is this possible?

```
class Foo(object):
    class Meta:
        pass

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        # remove the Meta class here?
        super(Bar, self).__init__()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot remove class attributes from an inherited base class; you can only *mask* them, by setting an instance variable with the same name:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Meta = None  # Set a new instance variable with the same name
        super(Bar, self).__init__()
```

Your own class could of course also override it with a class variable:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    Meta = None

    def __init__(self):
        # Meta is None for *all* instances of Bar.
        super(Bar, self).__init__()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it at the class level:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    Meta = None
```

(also `super`-calling the constructor is redundant)

Comment: "super-calling the constructor is redundant"?  The parent's `__init__` isn't called automatically.  If you want the parent's `__init__` called, you have to do it explicitly.

Comment: In his example, his `__init__` only calls the superclass's `__init__` and nothing else, which is automatic behavior if `__init__` isn't defined in the subclass (if I'm interpreting what you're saying correctly.)